# jquery localscroll question about vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created the following page http://kylehouston.com/testing/localscroll/ where I have a number of main links and then sublinks for these. At the moment when a main link is clicked the content scrolls vertically and when a sublink is clicked eg Blue Inner Link 1 the content slides horizontally.

My question is how can I update the script so that when I click a main link the content scrolls horizontally and when I click a sublink the content scrolls vertically?

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation I think you need to setup selectors that target the parents and children separately. Then set the axis property.

```
$('parent selector').localScroll({
  axis:'yx'
});

$('child selector').localScroll({
  axis:'xy'
});
```

Right now your code uses the same selector and default axis for everything

```
$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
```

Comment: thanks for this, would I need to float my sections to the left and remove the float left on each of the list items?